# Facebook api call - mutual friends - loop

Tags: c#, loops, facebook-graph-api, foreach, while-loop

I have this code which makes a call to Facebook API in order to get the mutual friends on the application for two given users. The parameter nextPage corresponds to facebook api's next page.
Problem is that although I have a limited number of common friends each time, I get errors from Facebook api, for having too many calls per second (about 5 milion/day overall). I tried mocking the call to facebook, to always return null, but that resulted in a CPU overloading due to w3p, with 99% usage. What am I missing?

```
public async Task<MutualFriendsModel> GetMutualFriends(Guid currentUserGuid,
        Guid visitedUserGuid, string nextPage)
{
    var currentUser = Get(currentUserGuid);
    var visitedUser = _serviceUserLogin.GetByUserId(visitedUserGuid);
    var mutualFriends = new MutualFriendsModel();
    var hasNextPage = true;
    while (hasNextPage && mutualFriends.Users.Count < 25)
    {
        var facebookResult = await
                     _facebookApi.GetMutualFriendsFacebookRequest(currentUser.Token,
                        visitedUser.ProviderKey, nextPage);
        if (facebookResult == null) break;
        mutualFriends.Update(facebookResult, this, _serviceUserLogin);
        nextPage = mutualFriends.NextPageUrl;
        hasNextPage = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(mutualFriends.NextPageUrl);
     }

     return mutualFriends;
}
```

Also, there is another variation of the above mentioned snippet, which only counts the mutual friends.

```
private async Task<IList<SavedCommentModel>> MutualFriendsCount(User currentUser,
                        IList<SavedCommentModel> comments)
{
    var usersFriends = new Dictionary<Guid, long>();
    foreach (var comment in comments)
    {
        if (usersFriends.ContainsKey(comment.UserId))
        {
            comment.TotalMutualFriends = usersFriends[comment.UserId];
        }
        else
        {
            var visitedUser = _serviceUserLogin.GetByUserId(comment.UserId);
            if (visitedUser.LoginProvider != LoginProvider.Facebook.ToString()) continue;
            var facebookResult = await
                            _facebookApi.GetMutualFriendsFacebookRequest(currentUser.Token, visitedUser.ProviderKey);
            if (facebookResult == null) continue;
            comment.TotalMutualFriends = facebookResult.Context.Mutual_friends.Summary.Total_Count;
            usersFriends.Add(comment.UserId, comment.TotalMutualFriends);
        }
    }
    return comments;
}
```